# Integration with Active Directory using spring boot ldap

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, spring-ldap

i am new to concept of active directory, so to integrate active directory with ldap i am using spring boot framework i.e using spring security with ldap.
So based on same reference from stackoverflow i am not able to managed authentication with active directory.

Below is my sample code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
}

@Bean
public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
            "xyzabcd.org", "ldap://192.168.100.161:389/");

    return activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=Users").contextSource(contextSource());
}

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://192.168.100.161:389/"),
            "DC=xyzabcd.org,DC=org");
}

}
```

with this i am getting below error

> Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
>
> Reason: Bad credentials

so guys please help me out with this problem
Thanks

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Sometimes there is an error code that you can lookup that will tell you exactly what it didn't like about the credentials.

Comment: @Grabriel Luci thanks for your response ,yes i am getting this error only